# Python writing data to file only works when run from console

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run

```
file = open("BAL.txt","w")
I = '200'
file.write(I)
file.close
```

from a script, it outputs nothing in the file. (It literally overwrites the file with nothing)

Furthermore, running cat BAL.txt just goes to the next line like nothing is in the file.

But if I run it line by line in a python console it works perfectly fine.
Why does this happen. ( I am a begginner learning python the mistake may be super obvious. I have thrown about 2 hours into trying to figure this out)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you mean `file.close()`?

Comment: @ChristianDean of course, there is an error without it

Comment: Yes I did I posted it wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't closing your file properly.  To close it you are missing the `()` at the end of  `file.close` so it should look like this:

```
file = open("BAL.txt", "w")
file.write("This has been written to a file")
file.close()
```

[This site has the same example and may be of some use to you.](https://programminghistorian.org/lessons/working-with-text-files)

---

Another way, especially useful when you are appending multiple values into a single file is to use something like `with open("BAL.txt","w") as file:`.  Here is your script rewritten to include this example:

```
I = '200'
with open("BAL.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(I)
```

This opens our file with the value `file` and allows us to write values to it.  Also note that `file.close()` is not needed here and when appending text `w+` needs to be used.

Comment: You don't need `file.close()` if you use `with`. In fact, I think it might error with "file already closed".

Comment: @AaronKlein  It returns no error for me but you  are right you don't need `file.close()`

Answer (score 3):

to write to a file you do this:

```
file = open("file.txt","w")
file.write("something")
file.close()
```

when you use `file.write()` it deletes all of the contents of the file, if you want to write to the end of the file do this:

```
file = open("file.text","w+")
file.write(file.read()+"something")
file.close()
```

There are other ways to do this but this one is the most intuitive (not the most efficient), also the other way tends to be buggy so there is no reason to post it because this is reliable.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? And please stop begging.

Comment: @StefanPochmann because this works anywhere that python is being run not only in the console

Comment: If this is the answer sought, it bears mentioning the **a** mode that can be passed to the [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open) method, which is pretty similar to **w+**.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're missing the parentheses when you're closing the file. Secondly, writing to a file should be done like this:

```
file = open("BAL.txt", "w")
file.write("This has been written to a file")
file.close()
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Much better to use a with block to close the file

Comment: @wwii When the block ends it will close the file handle for you.

Comment: What if there is an exception?

Comment: @wwii then you can use try to catch it.

Comment: @wwii it will still close the file, even if there is an exception, and then it will raise the exception again once the file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` statement automatically takes care of closing the file when the block of code is exited. This ensures that the file is properly closed, even if an error occurs while writing.

```
with open("BAL.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("This has been written to a file")
```